# How to execute SqlPackage command line to generate script without USE statement

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database, sqlpackage

How to get rid of the USE statement when using SqlPackage command line method when  the **target DB is a Azure Database** ?

When executing:

```
SqlPackage /a:script [...]
```

I always get :

```
GO
:setvar DatabaseName "databasename"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "databasename"
:setvar DefaultDataPath ""
:setvar DefaultLogPath ""

GO
:on error exit
GO
/*
Detect SQLCMD mode and disable script execution if SQLCMD mode is not supported.
To re-enable the script after enabling SQLCMD mode, execute the following:
SET NOEXEC OFF; 
*/
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO

USE [$(DatabaseName)];
```

And when executing this script :

```
sqlcmd -S [...] $pathToUpdateScript
```

I am getting this error message :

```
USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.
```

So, How do I remove the `USE` statement from the script generated by `SqlPackage /a:script` ? Is there a way to use any command line parameter to support this action ?